# Что возвращает такое преобразование (void *) для строки?

Tags: c++

Я написал такой код:

```
char * str = "abcdefg";
cout << str << " " << &str << " " << (void *) str;
```

Выводит следующее:

```
abcdefg 0x22feac 0x488000
```

Я сейчас читаю книгу "Язык программирования C++ (Прата С. 6-е издание)" и там написано примерно следующее: чтобы вывести адрес строки с помощью `cout` нужно применить такой синтаксис: `cout << (void *) str;`

Объясните пожалуйста почему `&str` и `(void *) str` выводят разные адреса и что вообще значит этот синтаксис: `(void *) str`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я совсем далёк от C++ нынче, но, если мне память не изменяет, то...

`(void *) str` - адрес, где строка лежит.

`&str` - это адрес указателя, тоже самое, что `char **`.

То есть, это не одно и то же.

Ну а `(void *)` это просто каст без привязки к типу. Если бы у вас был `int *`, то вы точно так же бы могли сделать каст `(void *)`, чтоб получать адрес.

Зачем это делается? Ну, скажем, вместо создания различных методов для `int`, `char`:

```
void myMethodForChar(char * arg){ ...}
void myMethodForInt(int * arg){ ...}
```

Вы можете создать один метод:

```
void myMethodForChar(void * arg){ ...}
```

И передавать туда, хоть указатель на `int`, хоть на `char`, предварительно преобразовав в `void *`.

Пускай знающие люди поправят, если неправ (:

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понятно почему так (=

Comment: @alek.kov да не за что (: если ответ помог, отметьте как подтверждённый.

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, строковый литерал должен быть присвоен типу `const char*` (или хотя бы `char[]`, если нужна модификация строки в дальнейшем), т.к. его нельзя изменить без возможности нарваться на UB. То, что компилятор позволяет написать без `const` оставлено для совместимости с Си-кодом. В C++ это будет неверным:

```
warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
```

Далее, `operator<<` (сдвиг влево) перегружен для потоковых (stream) классов в качестве операции вывода в поток. Перегрузка реализована для различных типов данных: целых, вещественных, строк, адресов ... Для пользовательского класса можно реализовать свою перегрузку. Какая из перегрузок `operator<<` будет вызвана зависит от типа правостороннего операнда. Для обычных указателей выводится адрес (т.е. значение, которое хранит указатель), но для строковых типов (а `char*` по соглашению является именно Си-строкой, а не просто указателем) работает перегрузка, которая выводит именно Си-строку, расположенную по переданному адресу.

Т.о. чтобы явно вывести адрес строки (адрес ее первого символа), а не саму строку, нужно для `operator<<` преобразовать правосторонний операнд к типу обычного указателя. `void*` при этом является обобщенным указателем, т.е. может легально указывать на любые типы данных. И преобразование вида `(void *) str` делает свое дело.

Следующий момент в том, что преобразование такого вида `(T) v` является преобразованием в Си-стиле, что по сути [сводится](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) к цепочке других преобразований. Для C++ варианта преобразование строки к обобщенному указателю должно быть написано в иной форме: `static_cast<const void*>(str)`.

Теперь к самим аргументам. `str` является указателем и содержит адрес строки, а значит `&str` это адрес, по которому расположен сам указатель `str` (ведь указатель тоже должен где-то храниться), содержащий адрес строки. Т.о. указатели имеют разные адреса, т.к. указывают на разные сущности.

[Итоговый код](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3721f1ea3ae041fd) будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char * str = "abcdefg";
    std::cout << str << " " << &str << " " << static_cast<const void*>(str);
}
```

Вывод:

```
abcdefg 0x7fff74013938 0x400915
```

Из которого, кстати, хорошо видно, что адрес указателя (`&str`) и адрес строки указывают в совершенно разные области памяти. Указатель расположен на стеке, а строка в защищенной для записи области памяти (скорее всего).

Answer (score 0):

`(void *)` - Это си-стайл приведения типов (C-style cast). Данной операцией ты `str` приводишь к `void *` собственно потому и вывод отличается от вывода `&str`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << str;
```

выведет строку, на которую указывает `str`, a

```
cout << (void *) str;
```

выведет значение самого указателя `str` (адрес).